# How to find the minimum number of vectors in $\mathbb{N}^n$ to exceed a given sum?

Tags: summation, vectors, discrete-optimization

Given a finite multiset $A$ of vectors $a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{N}^n$ where $n\geq 1$ and a target vector $b\in \mathbb{N}^n$, how can we find a smallest subset $S\subseteq A$ for which $\sum_{s\in S} s \geq b$ where $\geq$ denotes the component-wise comparison?

For vectors in $\mathbb{N}$, this is trivial as we can just sort $A$ descendingly and take the first $k$ elements such that their sum exceeds $b$ and $k$ is as small as possible. But how about higher dimensions?

My idea was the following: First define a distance function which "ignores" all coordinates of a vector which have already exceeded the target vector, i.e. $D(u,v):=d((u_{k_1},\dots,u_{k_m}),(v_{k_1},\dots,v_{k_m}))$ for only the $k_i \leq n$ such that $u_{k_i} < v_{k_i}$. Here, little $d$ is just the Euclidean metric (potentially in a smaller vector space since we "forget" coordinates). For vectors already exceeding the target vector in every component, $D$ is just defined to be zero. Now set $x$ to be the zero vector and repeatedly add an $a\in A$ to $x$ which minimises the distance $d(x,b)$, i.e. for every $a'\neq a$, $d(x+a',b)\geq d(x+a,b)$, until $d(x,b)=0$. After adding some $a$, an instance of it needs to be removed from the multiset $A$ of course.

Right now, I am trying to prove or disprove that this works. Has anyone got ideas or another strategy?

Comment: By the way, is there a better word for "vector" here? I know that $\mathbb{N}$ is not a vector space but I didn't want to call it "point" because of the summation.

Comment: Greedy algorithms usually don't work for these kind of problems. A counterexample for your algorithm could be $b=(4,8,4)$ and $A =\{(3,7,3), (4,0,4), (0,8,0)\}$. Your algorithm will choose $(3,7,3)$ as first option because it minimizes euclidean distance, but the better options are $(4,0,4), (0,8,0)$ and any other is a mistake. Edit: I wouldn't be surprised if this was NP-complete or harder, although right now I'm not sure about it.

Comment: That's true, thanks for the comment! Do you think another metric could fix that? But probably, you're right and greedy doesn't work here.

Comment: The worst case would probably be to just treat it as a graph problem where the initial node is the zero vector and we are using BFS or something similar to find the shortest path to a node with coordinates greater than b. Node coordinates would correspond to sums of different choices for S and edges would be elements of A. But that can get very inefficient... $|A|!$ edges, right?

Comment: I don't think so, almost any metric would fail in a similar example to the one before. Do you need this for practical purposes or is it just a theoretical question? This reminds me of [bin-packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), just with the inequalities reversed, so I would really look into that. If you can connect this with known problems like that one, you can use any "efficient" algorithm that's already known for it. Also for the question of naming, you can also use "tuple" although vector is fine because $\mathbb{N}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.
For each $s\in A$, let binary decision variable $x_s$ indicate whether $s\in S$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{s\in A} x_s$ subject to linear constraints
$$\sum_{s\in A} (a_{s})_i x_s \ge b_i \quad \text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Found the connection. This problem is at least harder than [Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) optimization problem with same $n$. Reason being if we have a collection $S$ of subsets from $\{1,2,..., n\}$, we can make tuples $t_m$ for each chosen subset, so that the subset $(i_1, ..., i_k)$ would be connected to a tuple $t_m$ that would have a $1$ in the positions $i_1, ..., i_k$ and a $0$ elsewhere. In this case, $A$ would be defined as the collection of all tuples $t_m$ defined in this process. An example, if $n$ was $5$ and $$S = \{\{1,2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{4,5\}\},$$ then the new tuples would be $$A = \{ (1,1,1,0,0), (0,1,0,1,0), (0,0,1,1,0), (0,0,0,1,1)\}.$$

If you had an algorithm to solve your problem with $b=(1,1,..., 1)$ and this $A$, then you could apply it to this subset and solve the Set Cover problem, because you would have minimized the number of sets that cover your $b$, and this would be the solution to the original problem.

So it's, at least, worse to solve than NP-hard. Now it would be nice to know if you can use a Set Cover algorithm to solve your problem, that is, going in the opposite direction to prove that it is actually NP-hard. But right now I don't see how to prove that, nor know if it's even true.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm looking for an actual algorithm to solve it, I'll have a look at bin-packing and probably solve it with a linear program. Do you think that the problem (in this case, the theoretical one) changes significantly when we allow positive real numbers?

Comment: @YpsilonZett Besides obvious observations like it doesn't change when you allow rational numbers, I don't know much else, it will probably affect it but I'm no expert.